# In which book did Poirot find a four-foot long clue?

Tags: agatha-christie, hercule-poirot, quote-source

In one of the Poirot books he mentions that though clues are often small he once found a four-foot long one.

Unfortunately I can't remember in which book he mentions this.

Does anyone know which book he did find the four-foot long clue in?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

He found it in *The Murder on the Links*, and he made that statement in *Lord Edgware Dies*.

In chapter 7 of *Lord Edgware Dies*, Poirot mentions this:

> ‘I found a clue once,’ said Poirot dreamily. ‘But since it was four feet long instead of four
>   centimetres no one would believe in it.’

(chapter 7)

This is in reference to *The Murder on the Links*, where a 4 (or two, see below) foot pipe is used to disfigure a victim's face to make it unrecognizable.

On a side note, in *The Murder on the Links*, the pipe is said to be two feet long.

> 'Eh bien! I also have found something! A piece of lead-piping.'
>
> 'Nonsense, Poirot. You know very well that's got nothing to do with it. I meant little things—traces that may lead us infallibly to the murderers.'
>
> 'Mon ami, a clue of two feet long is every bit as valuable as one measuring two millimetres!

(also in chapter 7)

This seems to just be a minor discrepancy, and I don't think the difference really matters.

Comment: The pipe had been *intended* to disfigure the face of a corpse's, but the perpetrator was forestalled and it was not actually used for this purpose—that was what made the clue so clever.